# Super cache caches mobile pages for desktop

Tags: cache

Super Cache doesn't separately cache mobile pages and desktop pages.

Sometimes I see a mobile cached pages on the desktop and the vice versa.

How to solve this?

Comment: Do you have conditionals in your theme for mobiles? Have you checked supercache support?

Comment: I just use the native Wordpress conditional `wp_is_mobile()`. Do you have any experiences with Hyper Cache? It has a separate-cache-for-mobile option.